# How can you automate monitor turning off and on in a notebook used as a server Body:

Tags: server, keyboard, laptop, monitor

I'm repurposing a notebook as a home server (running Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS). In order to save energy (and backlight lifetime), I'm looking for a way to automatically turn the monitor off and back on when I press a key.

Here are the specific requirements:

**Automatic turn on**: Notebook monitor should automatically turn on when I press any key on its physical keyboard and back off after a while.

**Automatic turn off**: It should turn back off some time after interaction.

I had success using `sudo vbetool dpms off` and `sudo vbetool dpms on` to switch monitor off and on while connected to the server on SSH.

I also had success using `evtest` to identify the keyboard in `/dev/input`.

With some AI help I used the following script and I run it as a service:

```
  #!/bin/bash

  while true; do
    sudo vbetool dpms off
    # turn on if anything from the keyboard
    sudo cat "\dev\input\event4" | (
        # Read a byte if any
        read -n 1
        sudo vbetool dpms on

        sleep 10 #seconds
    )
  done
```

I'm facing issues in detecting physical input to reactivate the monitor. Using sudo cat `\dev\input\event4` I see some garbage coming up when I press a key, but monitor doesn't back turn on when the service runs.

Could someone suggest a fix?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

KEYBOARD_DEVICE="/dev/input/event4"
IDLE_TIME=10

turn_off_monitor() {
  echo 'OFF'
  sudo vbetool dpms off
}

turn_on_monitor() {
  echo 'ON'
  sudo vbetool dpms on
}

turn_on_monitor

reset_timer() {
  if [[ -n $TIMER_PID ]]; then
    kill $TIMER_PID 2>/dev/null
  fi
  # Special for MURU from the comments: SLEEP, again...
  (sleep $IDLE_TIME; turn_off_monitor) &
  TIMER_PID=$!
}

reset_timer

sudo evtest "$KEYBOARD_DEVICE" | while read line; do
  turn_on_monitor
  reset_timer
done
```

I just tried myself and it works as expected. Initially, please comment out the lines **sudo vbetool dpms on** and **sudo vbetool dpms off**. Then, simply test in the terminal to ensure you see the **ON** and **OFF** messages as anticipated. After confirming this, you can uncomment the **vbetool** lines and test it again.

Comment: `# Wait for a specified time of inactivity`  and        `sleep 10 # seconds`? That doesn't compute. Do you know what `sleep 10` does? Is this AI generated?

Comment: @muru The topic starter's code is generated by AI, as mentioned, I just added "stdbuf -o0" to adjust the buffering of the output stream so the keyboard input data is processed immediately as it becomes available and "while read -n 1 keyPress; do" to read input from the keyboard. And you are right about topic starter's "sleep 10". Changed to "sleep 1" now.

Comment: That still misses the point: "Wait for inactivity" != what `sleep` does. (The OP's code didn't have that, so _you_ or the AI site you used added that)

Comment: @muru "sleep 10" results in a 10-second delay of inactivity before turning off the monitor. I believe this is self-explanatory. Another thing: I tried the code with /dev/input/event* and it didn't function properly for some reason. I modified the code to utilize evtest instead and now it's working as expected. If you could test it out yourself, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: "sleep 10" results in a 10-second delay of inactivity before turning off the monitor. I believe this is self-explanatory. " A script waiting for 10 seconds of inactivity from the user **is not the same as the script itself being inactive for 10 seconds**. That is also quite self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

Check manually:

```
sudo vbetool dpms off; sleep 5; sudo vbetool dpms on
```

If the monitor will not wake up after 5 seconds, something wrong with

```
sudo vbetool dpms on
```

Then please update the question with Edit button with the information if it worked or not.

Comment: thanks, this works fine

Comment: so then use the evtest tool to detect buttons are pushed and run "sudo vbetool dpms on" on pushed keys and "sudo vbetool dpms off" after some time of delay, test the code provided in the other comment, for me seems ok (I personally not tested though)